# Query a subcollection from a specific doc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my firestore databse looks like this:

groups ( collection ) => group of certain id ( doc ) => quizzes (subcollection)

All i want to do is to write a query in js that returns an array of all the quizzes from a group with a given id

The code i wrote looks like this:

```
  export const fetchQuizzesFirebase =  async function (idGroup) {
    if (!idGroup) return [];
    const quizzes = await firestore
      .collection(`groups`)
      .doc(idGroup)
      .collection(`quizzes`)
      .get();
  
    return quizzes.filter(doc => doc.exists).map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
  }
```

But it doesn't work and i can't seem to fix it. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems correct but you should use map on the `.docs` property instead of the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). I'll also make sure if that group ID exists by `console.log(idGroup)` and also that `.filter()` is redundant. You've received a querySnapshot and all documents in that exists.

```js
console.log(`${quizzes.size} quizzes found`) // Check quiz count
return quizzes.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
               ^^^^
```

Using a `map` only will do.

Comment: Thank you for help, i changed the way you said, i logged the id and it seems alright , but i get this error  `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): quizzes.map is not a function` , any ideas why?